# Drupal TB mega menu is so slow

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I'am developing a website using Drupal, and TB mega menu for my main menu, when i used Devel to check the execution time i found that TB mega menu is taking about 23978.991 ms on the folloing query :

**tb_megamenu_get_tree**

```
SELECT m.load_functions, m.to_arg_functions, m.access_callback, m.access_arguments, m.page_callback, m.page_arguments, m.delivery_callback, m.title, m.title_callback, m.title_arguments, m.type, m.description, ml.* FROM menu_links ml LEFT JOIN menu_router m ON m.path = ml.router_path WHERE ml.menu_name = :menu ORDER BY p1 ASC, p2 ASC, p3 ASC, p4 ASC, p5 ASC, p6 ASC, p7 ASC, p8 ASC, p9 ASC
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: I've been working with drupal for just over a year, may i recommend using the superfish module? Looks like it would provide the what you're after. Been using this and have never had any problems with load time etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it's either a lack of index on the JOIN condition, or in the ORDER BY clause. Adding the appropriate index would almost certainly help by orders of magnitude.

But I would also second Goon3r's recommendation of SuperFish. We use it and it works very well.